# To find the maximum available cache storage available in chrome programatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, google-chrome

I am using Angular 11 to build an app where I record the screen and store the recorded file in chrome storage. So I want to know if my recorded video size is crossing more than the available cache storage so that I can stop the recording and store it. My question is how can I know the available maximum storage space in chrome programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to store a recorded video inside the web storages that browsers offers... instead use your own or third party backend services to store data if you really need to persist that recorded video or use local variables to play around with the recorded video

Comment: I am storing the recorded video temporarily, just to make the video available for the users  as quick as possible. Later i will be pushing it to database and clear cache. But as the cache memory differs from each machine i want to alert the user to stop recording to save the video.